# How to cross compile OpenCV with ffmpeg

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile opencv with ffmpeg for arm.

I have cross compiled ffmpeg, how do I configure cmake to see the ffmpeg?

Edit: I am cross compiling for AR Drone 2.0. I use toolchain under platform/linux.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122724/setting-installing-up-opencv-2-4-6-1-on-ubuntu-12-04-02

Comment: @marol That guide has little to do with OP problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successful in cross compiling OpenCV with ffmpeg for AR Drone's ARM processor by writing my own toolchain file where I explicitly set all the linker, pkg_config and compiler paths to relevant directories containing the cross-compiled stuff.

I have written a blog post detailing the entire process here:
[How to Cross-Compile OpenCV with FFmpeg for AR Drone (ARM Processor)](http://hassannadeem.com/blog/2015/04/29/cross-compile-opencv-with-ffmpeg-ar-drone-arm/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific problem is to use `cmake-gui` which provides you a visual interface to ease the process of setting up variables, like your ffmpeg package location.

However I have 2 recommendations:

- Download the [most updated toolchain](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).
- **DO NOT USE [THIS GUIDE](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html)**. Use instead the toolchain that you find in the package in sources\platforms\android\android.toolchain.cmake: read inside, you'll find the **correct instructions** at the beginning of the file.

Another optional recommendation: use [ninja](https://github.com/martine/ninja/releases) as build system, much faster.

Comment: There is a checkbox to enable/disable ffmpeg but no ffmpeg include path option.
And btw i am cross compiling for AR Drone

Comment: @haxan7 You are right! You'll have to modify stuff in the source directory. You can reproduce the same that you find for Windows in `sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg`, and then touch a couple of places where you have conditional statements `if(WIN32)`. If you manage, please post an answer.