# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: How to install OpenCV highgui module

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu, highgui

I am trying to install the highgui module of opencv so that I can get a Qt Creator project to run properly.  However, continued searching of the internet has yielded absolutely nothing.

The project was originally configured to run using version 2.3 of highgui, but returns the error that libopencv_highgui.so.2.3 is missing.  I've searched the Internet for ways to install this module properly, but I've learned that many of its dependencies are as outdated as version 2.3 of highgui, so installing it is rather difficult.
I have managed to install the 2.4 version of highgui using sudo apt-get, but installing it this way does not create the any .so file.  What I seem to have difficulty getting is when/how/why are they created, and when/how/why aren't they created.   And if I can't get the exact right file, how do I make it so that Qt Creator looks for a different one that might actually exist?  For the second question, I assume I change libraries in the .pro file, but I haven't had much success.

Answer (score 0):

The modules are created during installation. Perhaps you got the error because opencv wasn't properly installed.

Could you specify how opencv was initially installed. If you don't need any special requirements, you can install from Ubuntu repository: `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` or by installing required dependencies manually and then building from source such as described in [Setting/Installing up OpenCV 2.4.6.1+ on Ubuntu 12.04.02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122724/setting-installing-up-opencv-2-4-6-1-on-ubuntu-12-04-02)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The first thing I had done was install it using a repository and the files I needed did not get created.  What happens then?

Comment: If you don't mind to re-install, uninstall `sudo apt-get remove libopencv-dev` then follow the guide in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122724/setting-installing-up-opencv-2-4-6-1-on-ubuntu-12-04-02. May I ask what version of opencv you're also trying to install?